# Как сверстать облако тегов на css?

Tags: html, css, frontend

Сейчас готов кусок `html` и `css` к нему, но верстка не соответствует макету и непонятно, как сделать `hover` при наведении и всплывающую подсказку над тегом.

```css
.tags {
  padding: 80px;
  width: 380px;
  /* Style for "jQuery" */
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.tags a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Style for "Rounded Re" */
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 13px;
  background-color: #090a0b;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="tags">
  <a href="#">Супер тег</a>
  <a href="#">Еще один тег</a>
  <a href="#">И еще тег</a>
  <a href="#">Классный тег</a>
  <a href="#">Вот тег последний</a>
</div>
```

При этом на выходе должно получится облако тегов с возможностью раскрыть его и при наведении hover с подсказкой https://yadi.sk/i/t7ATcCq23SqXoq

Comment: с `:hover` то в чем проблема? тултипы через js

Comment: непонятно как это реализовать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ну вот как вариант

```css
body {
  background: #1e2429;
}
.tags {
  padding: 80px;
  width: 380px;
  /* Style for "jQuery" */
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.tags a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Style for "Rounded Re" */
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 13px;
  background-color: #090a0b;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  
  position: relative; /* для подсказки */
}

/* это нужно, если есть необходимость что бы можно было навести курсор на подсказку. Иначе будет исчезать */
.tags a:after { 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.tags a:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
}
.tags a:hover {
  background: #eb1f63;
}

/* оформление плашки */
.tags__hide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  line-height: 1;
  transition: all .3s;
  
  /* параметры для изчезновения/появления. Можете настроить как вам угодно */
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.tags a:hover .tags__hide {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: calc(100% + 15px);
}
/* треугольник */
.tags__hide:before {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="tags">
  <a href="#">
    Супер тег
    <span class="tags__hide">text hide</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">Еще один тег</a>
  <a href="#">И еще тег</a>
  <a href="#">Классный тег</a>
  <a href="#">Вот тег последний</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tags-list {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.tags-list>li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.tags-list>li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.tags-list>li>a:hover {
  background: #f00;
}

.tags-list>li>a[data-tooltip]:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -100%;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.tags-list>li>a[data-tooltip]:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -10px;
  margin-left: -7px;
  border-top: 7px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  content: "";
}

.tags-list>li>a[data-tooltip]:before,
.tags-list>li>a[data-tooltip]:after {
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.tags-list>li>a[data-tooltip]:hover:after,
.tags-list>li>a[data-tooltip]:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tags-list">
  <li><a href="#" data-tooltip="ToolTip">Супер тег</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-tooltip="ToolTip">Супер тег</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-tooltip="ToolTip">Супер тег</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-tooltip="ToolTip">Супер тег</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-tooltip="ToolTip">Супер тег</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-tooltip="ToolTip">Супер тег</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-tooltip="ToolTip">Супер тег</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-tooltip="ToolTip">Супер тег</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-tooltip="ToolTip">Супер тег</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно попробовать добавить псевдоэлемент `::before` и скрыть его `display: none;`, а при наведении `display: block;`, скачать иконочный шрифт в виде всплывающего облака, но не уверен, надо проверять.

При наведении:

```
.tags a:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to top right, #f5755a, #f136ef);
}
```

Comment: Если не уверены, то лучше не отвечайте:)